# Plotting 2 fixed factors and continuous covariates

Tags: r, data-visualization, fixed-effects-model, continuous-data

I measured the reflected radiation: the independent variables are the incoming radiation (continuous), the treatment (Control-Encroached; fixed) and the height (1-3; fixed).

I want to plot these in R, but I'm struggling with defining each factor. This is what I have at this moment:

```
plot(Ri,Ro,type='n',xlab='Rin (W/m²)',ylab='Rout (W/m²)',las=1,xlim=c(0,1100),ylim=c(0,300))
points(Ri[tr=='E'],Ro[tr=='E'],pch=19)
points(Ri[tr=='C'],Ro[tr=='C'],pch=1)
abline(lm(Ro[tr=='E']~Ri[tr=='E']),lty=1)
abline(lm(Ro[tr=='C']~Ri[tr=='C']),lty=2)

legend(0,300,legend=c('Control','Encroached'),pch=c(1,19),lty=c(2,1))
```

[image: Rout~Rin]

But I would like to make a distinction between the treatments, within each height. The problem is, I don't know what the R-script is to obtain this.

Comment: Note that questions focusing on the code in some specific software are off-topic here. Please read advice in the Help Center.

Comment: In any language, the skewness and especially the approximately multiplicative relationships evident here imply use of, or at least experiment with, logarithmic scales for both axes.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a small multiple plot, using height in each panel, as a good starting point. The level of complexity in scatterplots is often too great to pile on more point or line patterns and still have clear patterns. That is not such a problem with small multiples though.

Here is a simple example in R using the `ggplot2` library, although such plots can similarly be accomplished in base graphics or other libraries.

```
library(ggplot2)
iris$control <- sample(c("Control","Treatment"),150,replace=TRUE)
p <- ggplot(data=iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length, color=control)) +
     geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="lm",se=FALSE) + facet_wrap(~Species)
p
```

[image]